# Stop program(containing recursive function) after certain time

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Lets say i want to close program after x seconds (not #define)

My program is running a recursive function (recursive tree)

What can I do to make the running time of the program available from everywhere no matter the recursion depth, my first idea was to use a pointer as function parameter but I got confused real fast.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the start time in a global variable, and find the difference between the current time and that time in your recursive function.

```
#include <time.h>

static time_t start_time;

static void f(void) {
   // ...
   time_t current_time = time(NULL);
   int diff = current_time - start_time;
   // ...
}

int main(void) {
   start_time = time(NULL);
   f();
   return 0;
}
```

You could pass the start time as a parameter, but there's no point to passing the same value to each recursive call. It just eats up your available stack space for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main solutions to this problem, the first is have a global or class/struct data member that you can access at anytime in this function.

The second is add an extra parameter to your function and then just keep re passing it recursively, in this case you want to do it by reference to avoid copying each time you pass.

A final solution which I can think of is if your language supports static variables within functions, then when you first call the function, you check if this static variable is null, if so initialize.

Comment: Re "*in this case you want to do it by reference to avoid copying each time you pass.*", No. Copying a pointer (probably 64 bits) isn't better than copying a `time_t` (probably 64 bits). You'd just be adding complexity for nothing. This approach could make sense for larger structures, but not in this case.

Comment: Furthermore, given that the value never changes, using a parameter (whether a pointer or a `time_t`) is a bad idea in this case because you'd be wasting precious stack space. Using a parameter would make sense if the value changes, but that's not the case here.